# does Aitareya Brahmana say "the gods created this Rudra/PaShupati from the most terrible parts of themselves."?

Tags: rudra, aitareya-brahmana

A blog says The aitareya brahmaNa mentions this.

What does "terrible parts" mean here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The blogger is probably referring to this section of Aitareya Brahmana:

https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.104263/page/n151/mode/2up

> (Prajapati's Illegal Intercourse with his Daughter, and the
> Consequences of it. The Origin of Bhutavan.)
>
> The gods saw it (crying), "Prajapati commits an act never done
> (before)." (In order to avert the evil consequences of this incestuous
> act) the gods inquired for some one who might destroy the evil
> consequences (of it). Among themselves they did not find any one who
> might do that (atone for Prajapati's crime). **They then put the most
> fearful bodies (for the gods have many bodies) of theirs in one. This
> aggregate of the most fearful bodies of the gods became a god,
> Bhutavan, by name.** For he who knows this name only, is born. The gods
> said to him, "Prajapati has committed an act which he ought not to
> have committed. Pierce this (the incarnation of his evil deed)."
> So he did. He then said, "I will choose a boon from you." — They said,
> "Choose." He then chose as his boon sovereignty over cattle (`32`). That
> is the reason that his name is pasuman), i.e., having cattle. He who
> knows on this earth only this name (pasuman), becomes rich in cattle.
>
> `32`: `This appears to confirm Sayana's opinion that Rudra or Siva is here alluded to. For he is called pasupati, master of cattle.`

Given the context, "fearful parts/bodies" of gods is probably a more accurate translation than "terrible parts".